# How to sum up columns in a 2d array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to make a program that adds the columns of a 2d array and returns the smallest sum. this is the program that I wrote but i want to know if there is a more effeciant way. the main program was given to us by the professor. i want to know if there is a way of doing this without having to declare an integer for each column because what if its not always 3 columns, thank you.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

   int smallCol( int x[][3], int row, int col){

    int c1 = 0;
    int c2 = 0;
    int c3 = 0;
    int min;

    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < col; c++ ){
            if(c==0)
                c1 += x[r][c];
            if(c==1)
                c2 += x[r][c];
            if(c==2)
                c3 += x[r][c];    

            }


        }

    min = c1;

    if(c2 < c1)
        min = c2;

    if(c3 < c2)
        min = c3;

    return min;    
}


  int main() {
  int x[2][3] = {{3, 1, 4}, {1, 5, 9}};
  cout << "Smallest column sum is " << smallCol (x, 2, 3) << endl;
  // from the 2-d array x that has size 2 x 3, find the smallest col sum
  // output will be 4 since col#0 contains 3 and 1 is smallest.
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: How long will it take you to support, oh, say 2d array with 100 columns? That's a comparatively small 2d array, you know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use only one variable if you switch the nested loops:

```
#include <limits>

int smallCol( int x[][3], int row, int col){

    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    // or something really big... like 2147483647

    for (int c = 0; c < col; ++c ) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int r = 0; r < row; ++r ) {
            sum += x[r][c];
        }
        if ( min > sum ) {
            min = sum;
        }
    }  
    return min;    
}
```

**EDIT**

If you can't modify the main structure of the program as it's assigned, you can use a vector to store the partial totals and then scan it to find the minimum:

```
std::vector<int> sums(col);

for (int r = 0; r < row; ++r ) {
    for(int c = 0; c < col; ++c ) {
        sums[c] += x[r][c];
    }
}
for( int c = 0; c < col; ++c ) {
    if ( min > sums[c] ) {
        min = sums[c];
    }
}
```

This may be more cache friendly for very big matrices too, due to the contiguity of the elements in memory, resulting in a faster code.

Comment: iterating over rows before columns is almost always going to make the code very slow (i've seen 10x or more) because of cacheing issues.

Comment: agreed, for this it isn't huge. I was just thinking about " i want to know if there is a more efficient way" and "because what if its not always 3 columns" and didn't want him to get the impression that finding a way to do it with 1 variable meant it was better/more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of your nested loops, so you first loop over the columns and calculate a total for all rows in that column. Then you don't need a variable for each column's total.

```
int min;
for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        total += x[r][c];
    }
    if (c == 0 || total < min) {
        min = total;
    }
}
```

The `c == 0` test makes the first column be treated specially, so it initializes `min` to the total from the first column. The remaining columns will be compared to that.

Comment: Well, at least we are initializing `min` in different ways... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
int smallCol
{
    auto min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    for (auto i = 0; i < col; ++i)
    {
        auto m = std::accumulate(x, x + row, 0, [i](int sum, auto && row) { return sum + row[i]; });
        if (m < min) min = m;
    }

    return min;
}
```